# Reason for it telling me NullPointerexception

Tags: java, arrays

Why is this giving me the error of Nullpointerexception? It is happening on the 3rd line of my code, so my first for loop. Just so you know, this is a method with access to other parts of a larger code.

```
public static void insertionsort() 
{
    for (int outer = 1; outer < array.length; outer++)//Outer=next number to be sorted 
    { 
        String temp = array[outer]; //Stores it for later use
        int inner = outer; // inner used to track shifts 
        while (inner > 0 && array[inner - 1].compareTo(temp) >= 0) 
        {  
            array[inner] = array[inner - 1];//Swaps the number
            inner--;// Decrements
        } //shift them all right until one is smaller 
        array[inner] = temp;//Now it will put the stored number into its ordered position. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `array != null` ?

Comment: It's happening because `array` is `null`.

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't give any error. Are you sure you have initialized the array?

Comment: @MehmetSedatGüngör If that is the case, maybe it is just my JVM. I have it initialized above and it is being used by my other methods with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `array` is not defined in this line

```
for (int outer = 1; outer < array.length; outer++)//Outer=next number to be sorted
```

If this is a function parameter then add it like this

```
public static void insertionsort(int[] array) 
{
     for (int outer = 1; outer < array.length; outer++)//Outer=next number to be sorted
```

or define it inside

```
public static void insertionsort() 
{

    int[] array = {2,1,4,7,6,3};

    for (int outer = 1; outer < array.length; outer++)//Outer=next number to be sorted
```

Comment: The variable array is defined earlier and is able to be accessed by all other methods of my code. It is being used by other methods without this problem.

Comment: The only way you can have an exception in that line is if either `outer` or `array` is null. since you are defining outer there, the only possibility is array is null.

Comment: Really? Have you any idea why it would be giving me this problem just for this method though ? I am using other methods which call the array and use it and they are causing no problems. I just find it very weird. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: +1. Another option would be `array` is a class variable that isn't initialized yet when `array.length` is called.

Comment: @dic19 good idea, i have it defined in another class. Though I need it there for my entire program to work.

Comment: you may want to put a check in the method to see if the array is empty

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Just did this, it is printing null every time. Now i know what is causing this, I need to figure out why! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a unit test to reproduce the NPE, and I didn't get any error. My suggestion is to split the for sentece in multiple lines, so you will get exactly where is the NPE.

```
    for (int outer = 1; 
            outer < array.length; 
            outer++)//Outer=next number to be sorted 
    {
```

The full unit test is:

```
package src.test.java;  
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestOne {


   private static String[] array={"sa","se","si","so", "su"};
   @Test
   public void TestOne(){
    this.insertionsort();
   }

   public static void insertionsort() 
   {
    for (int outer = 1; 
            outer < array.length; 
            outer++)//Outer=next number to be sorted 
    { 
        String temp = array[outer]; //Stores it for later use
        int inner = outer; // inner used to track shifts 
        while (inner > 0 && array[inner - 1].compareTo(temp) >= 0) 
        {  
            array[inner] = array[inner - 1];//Swaps the number
            inner--;// Decrements
        } //shift them all right until one is smaller 
        array[inner] = temp;//Now it will put the stored number into its ordered position. 
    }
}
```

}